# How to start Role Playing as a complete group of beginners?

Tags: gm-techniques, character-creation

As the title says, we are a group of 4 complete beginners in Role Playing but we are very determined to start by one or two sessions.

We thought of using the D&D system, with everyone preparing his own character in advance.

I tend to be quite creative in everything related to writing, which makes me think that I could be our DM, writing and controlling the narrative.

My question is simple, to make this as enjoyable as possible, for the group and also for me as the DM, what would be your tips for a first 3 or 4 hours session ?

Thanks in advance for your widsom,

Guigzer, a wannabe DM.

Edit post-answer :
Apologies for the lack of precision.

I am mostly concerned on what guidelines should I follow on the whole scenario writing part to assure a smooth run for beginners.

The same would go the the character creation part for the player. Is there anything I should make sure of, such as concordance between the characters background and the scenario for example ?

Is there any support that I should prepare, for me and/or the players ?

The question was open since I don't know where to start really.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Open-ended suggestion prompts don't fit well here. Could you clarify what specific problems or difficulties you foresee that you need help with?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, just not one that currently fits the way we ask and answer here. I'd very much recommend taking the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for even more information. Our [chat] isn't super active, but once you have 20 rep you can pop in there to talk about these more open-ended prompts.

Comment: What do you mean by D&D system?